# scipy distributions provide zero for values smaller than loc (mean)

Tags: python, scipy, gamma-distribution

For the data yielding the below histogram, I used `gamma.fit(data)` function. It yields `(0.2856629839547822, 0.001612367540316285, 1.3126526078419007)` which must be the `alpha, loc`, and `scale` parameters of the distribution. However, the mean and standard deviations are `m=0.04181341484525036` and `s=0.02581912984507876` for the given dataset. The PDF is zero below the mean (`m`) value. I couldn't find any questions about this problem. What am I missing?

Histogram of the data
[image]

Comment: Welcome to SO. I suggest providing [a minimal, complete, and reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Could you detail your exact question a bit?  Are you sure your samples come from a gamma distribution? Maybe you'd want to fix the `loc` parameter during the fit, e.g. `gamma.fit(data, floc=0)`?  (Don't forget to add test data to your question.)

Answer (score 0):

The PDF is most definitely not zero for all values below your calculated mean. I fact, over 40% of the PDF area resides at `x<=m`:

```py
from scipy import stats

g = stats.gamma(0.2856629839547822, 0.001612367540316285, 1.3126526078419007)
m=0.04181341484525036

print(g.cdf(m))

0.4078
```